# Showing all values from list of dictionaries in jinja

Tags: python, html, arrays, dictionary, jinja2

I have an array:

```
videos = [{
    "id":1,
    "title": "Как построить открытую террасу к дому своими руками",
    "src": "http://videohost.me/hDX4hWWV5Ok.mp4",
},{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "How To Learn Anything 10x Faster",
    "description": "Interested in learning more about Charisma University? You’re going to spend thousands and thousands hours learning over the course of your life.  What’s crazy is that despite the fact that we have all those hours sitting in the classroom, learning musical instruments, martial arts, business, language, whatever - no one teaches us how to optimize that learning experience.",
    "src": "http://videohost.me/YLwFbwPbq.mp4",
}]
```

I try to print in website in html all titles from dictionary:

```
{% for video in videos %}
    <h2>{{ video.title}} </h2>
    <h2>{{ video.id}} </h2>
    <p></p>
    <video src="{{ video.src }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

But it shows only first title. What is the reason and I how can I solve my problem?

Comment: I don't understand how you're accessing the keys in video by `video.id`, afaik python doesn't allow this. I think it should be `video["id"]`. Besides, the jinja code seems alright.

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify:

```
<video src="{{ video.src }}" />
```

to

```
<video src="{{ video.src }}"></video>
```

It is a browser matter.

**Clarification**

Before making the modification above, if you try to `view page source` in the broser, you find:

```
    <h2>Как построить открытую террасу к дому своими руками </h2>
    <h2>1 </h2>
    <p></p>
    <video src="http://videohost.me/hDX4hWWV5Ok.mp4" />

    <h2>How To Learn Anything 10x Faster </h2>
    <h2>2 </h2>
    <p></p>
    <video src="http://videohost.me/YLwFbwPbq.mp4" />
```

Therefore, there is no problem with jinja, it is a browser matter.